# subprocess.run gnu parallel invocation

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I am trying to do a subprocess.call to gnu parallel (more for learning than anything), but for some reason I have not been successful.

So, the vanilla gnu parallel call:

```
/usr/bin/parallel echo ::: A B C
A
B
C
```

Now I make the same call within python subprocess.run:

```
cp = subprocess.run(["/usr/bin/parallel", "echo ::: A B C"])
parallel: Warning: Input is read from the terminal. You either know what you
parallel: Warning: are doing (in which case: YOU ARE AWESOME!) or you forgot
parallel: Warning: ::: or :::: or to pipe data into parallel. If so
parallel: Warning: consider going through the tutorial: man parallel_tutorial
parallel: Warning: Press CTRL-D to exit.
```

What am I missing here :( I have looked through the documentation of subprocess.run but I havent found a solution for this :(

I also tried:

```
cp = subprocess.run(["/usr/bin/parallel echo ::: A B C"])
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/bin/parallel echo ::: A B C': '/usr/bin/parallel echo ::: A B C'
```

not entirely sure what could be wrong!

Answer (score 0):

It works correctly with this format:

```py
subprocess.run(["parallel", "echo", ":::", "A", "B", "C"])
```

```
A
B
C
Out: CompletedProcess(args=['parallel', 'echo', ':::', 'A', 'B', 'C'], returncode=0)
```